# Need to wrap "ReflexSplitter" component from "react-reflex" libray

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flexbox

Firstly, great library I must say and I will be using this library to create `<SplitterContainer />`, `<SplitterElement />` and `<SplitterControl />` components inside the custom UI library I am building which will then be used by developers in the organization.

I was able to successfully wrap the `ReflexContainer` and `ReflexElement` components but I see a challenge in wrapping the `ReflexSplitter` component. As I saw in some of the closed issues, there's an `element.type` check that checks if the component is `ReflexSplitter`. Therefore, `ReflexSplitter` must be a direct child.

[image: snippet]

In my case, I want to customize the splitter as shown below and provide it as a component from my library.

[image: custom-splitter]

Now I see it can be done like

```
<ReflexSplitter>
  <InnerSplitter />
</ReflexSplitter>
```

but this needs to be a re-usable component, namely `<SplitterControl />`.

***The challenge I am facing currently***

I have two `<SplitterElement/ >` and ideally, the flex property for these should be `flex: 0.5 1 0%` but what I am getting is `flex: 0.3333 1 0%`. That means the wrapper `<SplitterControl />` component is being treated as a separate element.
[image]

How can I fix this?

Sandbox for the same
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/gallant-borg-49mxty

Answer (score 0):

There's no way around to wrap the `<ReflexSplitter />` component. The only solution is to expose the component from your app by a different name and have a children component inside `<ReflexSplitter />`.

```
export { ReflexSplitter as SplitterControl } from 'react-reflex';

<SplitterControl>
  <SplitterButtons />
</SplitterControl>
```